# Как задать произвольные значения по оси matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Возможно ли в matplotlib осуществить следующую штуку: по оси сделать возрастающе-убывающую последовательность, не используя метод xticklabels().
Нужно что-то подобное:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Да, возможно. Примените `FixedFormatter()` с последовательностью таких значений, какие вы хотите.

`FixedFormatter()` требует `FixedLocator()`, чтобы знать, куда рисовать ваши значения:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, FixedFormatter
import numpy as np

VALUES = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

# Пример функции - здесь будет ваша:
x = np.linspace(-2.4 * np.pi, +2 * np.pi, 200)
y = 5.4 * np.sinc(x) + x/3 + 4.1

ax = plt.axes()
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(range(-8, 7)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedFormatter(VALUES))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Aleksandr Sevastyanov, не стоит. Вы можете принять мой ответ (клик на галочку возле него), когда он для вас полезный. См. [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)